# Access a raw disk in Random Access mode C++

Tags: c++, winapi, ioctl

Now, I'm already familiar with the DeviceIoControl (ioctl) process and can read from a disk sequentially, 512 bytes at a time.

I create a handle from the list of \.\PhysicalDrive(s) and identify it via IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY command. Then process the desired device for data.

At this point, I can read it progressively by creating a loop that advances the read area 1 sector each time with this code (Qt C++ environment)

```
#include <minwindef.h>

#include <devioctl.h>
#include <ntdddisk.h>
#include <ntddscsi.h>

#include <ioapiset.h>
#include <fileapi.h>
#include <handleapi.h>
#include <winbase.h>

...

HANDLE devHandle = NULL;
devHandle = CreateFile(charArray, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0 ,NULL);

unsigned long secCount = 0;
while(true)
{
        bSuccess = ReadFile(devHandle, lpSecBuf, 512, &dwRead, NULL);

        if (bSuccess & (dwRead < 512))
        {
            qDebug()<<"EOF";
            break;
        }

        if(!bSuccess)
        {
            qDebug()<<"No data could be read from the device.";
            break;
        }

        if(bSuccess && dwRead>0)
        {
            qDebug()<<"Sector "<<secCount<<" data : "<<lpSecBuf;
        }

        secCount++;
}
```

Doing this sequentially means I have to progress through the sectors one by one, counting, until I reach the sector number I want to access. And this is not very optimal in performance.

What if I wanted to access a specific region directly, like "go to sector 45535 and read 512 bytes"? Does IOCTL operation even allow random access like this? I understand there are Random Access flags to a `CreateFile` call but after that, what? The read function still doesn't allow me to pass any arguments as "destination" or something like that, as far as I can see.

For example, HxD the hex editor can count the number of total sectors in a disk immediately and can go to a certain sector at any time. The function I need is similar to this capability.

[image: HxD Disk Read Function]

I have collected various tips as to how it can be done but I'm practically at an impasse here.

Any ideas would be welcome.

Comment: [SetFilePointer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365541.aspx)

Comment: you need set `offset` and `OffsetHigh` in `OVERLAPPED` and use this  `OVERLAPPED` as last param in `ReadFile`

Comment: I don't see any Qt code in this question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The read function still doesn't allow me to pass any arguments as
>   "destination" or something like that, as far as I can see.

this is not true - read again about [`ReadFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467(v=vs.85).aspx)

> lpOverlapped [in, out, optional]
>
> For an hFile that supports byte offsets, if you use this parameter you
>   must specify a byte offset at which to start reading from the file or
>   device. This offset is specified by setting the Offset and OffsetHigh
>   members of the OVERLAPPED structure.

and this:

> Considerations for working with file handles:
>
> •If lpOverlapped is not NULL, the read operation starts at the offset
>   that is specified in the OVERLAPPED structure ...

---

the I/O Manager maintains the current file position. ( look for `LARGE_INTEGER CurrentByteOffset` member of [`FILE_OBJECT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545834(v=vs.85).aspx) ). `ReadFile` and `WriteFile` updates the current file position by adding the number of bytes read or written when it completes the operation. also we can set this position by call `SetFilePointer[Ex]`

if we open file in synchronous mode (without `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` flag) all operations with file is sequential - any new operation  not begin execute until previous not finished.

in this case we have two options :

1. we can specify that the current file position offset be used. this
   specification can be made by pass a `NULL` pointer for
   `lpOverlapped`
2. we can reset this position by passing an explicit `lpOverlapped`
   value to `ReadFile` or `WriteFile`. Doing this automatically changes
   the current file position to that `(Offset, OffsetHigh)` value,
   performs the read(write) operation, and then updates the position
   according to the number of bytes actually read(write). This
   technique gives the caller atomic seek-and-read(write) service.

so by code we have 2 variants:

```
BOOL _ReadFile(HANDLE hFile, LARGE_INTEGER ByteOffset, PVOID lpBuffer, DWORD nNumberOfBytesToRead, LPDWORD lpNumberOfBytesRead)
{
#if 1
    OVERLAPPED ov = {};
    ov.Offset = ByteOffset.LowPart;
    ov.OffsetHigh = ByteOffset.HighPart;

    return ReadFile(hFile, lpBuffer, nNumberOfBytesToRead, lpNumberOfBytesRead, &ov);
#else
    if (SetFilePointerEx(hFile, ByteOffset, 0, FILE_BEGIN))
    {
        return ReadFile(hFile, lpBuffer, nNumberOfBytesToRead, lpNumberOfBytesRead, 0);
    }
    return FALSE;
#endif
}
```

of course atomic seek-and-read(write) much more effective compare using `SetFilePointer[Ex]` (additional API call to kernel).

if we open file in asynchronous mode (with `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` flag) - multiple read/write operations with file can executed at same time. in this case I/O Manager can not use the file position in `FILE_OBJECT` - because this undefined behavior here.

so we must always explicit pass `lpOverlapped` with valid offset. if we pass a `NULL` pointer for lpOverlapped - we got `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` error

at the last but important. from MSDN (at [ReadFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365467(v=vs.85).aspx) and [WriteFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747(v=vs.85).aspx) pages)

> The system updates the **OVERLAPPED** offset before **ReadFile** (**WriteFile**)
>   returns.

this is not true and mistake in documentation - you can check yourself that `OVERLAPPED` offset not updated after operation. may be mean that current file position (`CurrentByteOffset` in `FILE_OBJECT`) is updated. but again `OVERLAPPED` offset is **not updated** after operation

Comment: I had discarded 'lpOverlapped' parameter at first because I thought it was solely related to "asynchronous operation" and had nothing to do with offset mapping. I will look into it more rigorously. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @DoğukanTunç - I add more info to answer for maximum clarity

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation, it really helped me understand the idea and use it in my code.